# How to make iframe use all height available to it

Tags: css, html, iframe, node-webkit

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    html, body, iframe {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }

    header {
      height: 34px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    footer {
      height: 17px;
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <iframe src="https://freebsd.org"></iframe>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the header and footer stay fixed, always visible even when resizing and iframe take the remaining space? a.i. I want the layout to stay fixed, with scrollbar showing up only for iframe.

I think I tried everything, with as much googling as I could stomach, but nothing has worked to achieve this goal. Either iframe is not fully visible, it overflows over footer or the header or something else goes wrong.

So far I only tried CSS solutions, because I refuse to believe this is not possible with CSS alone, but if there is really no other way, JS solution is OK too.

I am doing for a nw.js application, footer and header will be for window controls, so I need them to be visible all the time.

Comment: You might be getting hung up on the iFrame part. This is the same as any site template with a fixed header and footer. Get a DIV to take up the space you want and then swap it out with an iFrame (or put the iFrame inside of that). There are tons of tutorials for CSS only templates with a fixed header and footer out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you what you're looking for (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a5oux4s8/):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

html, body, header, iframe, footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    height: 34px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

iframe {
    border: none;
    height: calc(100% - 51px);
    margin-top: 34px;
}

footer {
    height: 17px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

It will only work if you don't need to support older browsers because of the calc() function (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). If you do need to support older browsers, there are ways around it. Just let me know.

Comment: Thank you! you saved my sanity. Now I understand what the issue was. I don't care about the old browsers, since this is for node-webkit application.